# Updating the values in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a few questions.

I create a dictionary using set like this:

```
dict1 = dict()
dict1 = {'odd':{1,3,5},'even':{2,4,6}}
```

When I call odd, that is

```
dict1['odd']
```

It shows

```
{1, 3, 5}
```

Could I update the set inside the dictionary, say add 7 inside the key 'odd'?

I mean, when I call odd, the program will show

```
{1, 3, 5, 7}
```

I had tried to use add but I could not make it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`add`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.add) method in [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) as:

```
dict1 = {'odd':{1,3,5},'even':{2,4,6}}

dict1['odd'].add(7)

print(dict1)
{'odd': {1, 3, 5, 7}, 'even': {2, 4, 6}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could I update the set inside the dictionary, say add 7 inside the key 'odd'?

Sure. As you have already figured out, you get the value for the key `'odd'` via `dict1['odd']`. This is the `set` `{1, 3, 5}`.

All you have to do is use the `add` method of this set.

Very explicit:

```
>>> dict1 = {'odd':{1,3,5},'even':{2,4,6}}
>>> set_to_update = dict1['odd']
>>> set_to_update.add(7)
>>> 
>>> dict1['odd']
>>> {1, 3, 5, 7}
```

... or shorter: `dict1['odd'].add(7)`.

On a sidenote, your line `dict1 = dict()` is useless. You don't need to instantiate an empty dict before assinging the name `dict1` to the dict-literal `{'odd':{1,3,5},'even':{2,4,6}}`.